# Can NonlinearModelFit be used instead of TimeSeriesModelFit without loss of generality?

Tags: fitting, time-series, nonlinear, modeling

I am trying to model sales seasonality. As I am unfamiliar with `TimeSeriesModelFit[]`, I am using `NonlinearModelFit[]`. However, the result does not fit the data at all.

```
myRandom[a_,b_,c_,d_,x_]:=a+b*x+c*Sin[d*x]+RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[]]
myData=Flatten[Table[{x,myRandom[10,0.04,1,2*Pi/12,x]},{i,1,100},{x,1,48}],1];
myFit=NonlinearModelFit[myData,a+b*x+c*Sin[d*x],{a,b,c,d},x];
myFitEquation[x_]=Normal[myFit]
Show[ListPlot[myData],Plot[{10+0.04*x+1*Sin[2*Pi/12*x],myFitEquation[x]},{x,1,48}]]
myFit["RSquared"]
```

Two questions arise:

- Can you use any model with a *t*-variable to represent a time series *in theory*? Or is there something fundamentally different about series when interpreting the *t*-variable as 'time'?
- What causes *Mathematica* to fail to find the correct parameters for the specific model above? How does `NonlinearModelFit` estimate the parameters to begin with?

Comment: You need good starting values for `a`, `b`, `c` and `d`, especially since your model function is quite oscillatory. Also, `TimeSeries[]` and `NonlinearModelFit[]` serve completely different purposes...

Comment: I can understand that any multiple of `d` gives a local optimum within parameter space. Is this why _Mathematica_ fails to find the correct `d`? Or are there other things to consider?

Comment: I meant to say `TimeSeriesModelFit[]` instead of `TimeSeries[]`. Thank you. I have edited my original question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer to your question which includes the phrase "without loss of generality" is "No".

Generally (well, almost always) with a time series there is a more complicated covariance structure than what `NonlinearModelFit` assumes.  (However, `NonlinearModelFit` can be used to obtain starting values for the non-stochastic part of the model.)

Your simulated data is not really a time series for two reasons:  (1) you have multiple observations for the same value of `t` and (2) you've generated data where the errors are completely independent of each other between time periods.

You should follow @J.M. 's advice that good starting values are essential and especially because of the oscillatory nature of the function which results in a very bumpy likelihood surface.

So how to get good starting values?  A plot of the data gives good clues for what you should use.  Here's your data:

```
ListPlot[myData, Frame -> True]
```

[image: Plot of data]

We see that the initial data values start around 10 or 11.  So we set the initial value of `a` to 11.

For `b` we see that there are peaks around `t=3` and `t=39` with corresponding means of 11.1 and 12.6.  That suggests using (12.6-11.1)/(39-3) = 0.042 for `b`.

The difference between neighboring peaks and troughs is around 1.9 so using 1.9/2 for `c` is reasonable.

Finally we see that there are around 4 complete cycles over 48 time units so we use 4*2 Pi/48 for `d`.  You can get the coordinates for all of this by right-clicking the figure:

[image: Data and menu]

Now we have

```
myFit = NonlinearModelFit[myData, a + b*x + c*Sin[d*x],
  {{a, 11}, {b, (12.6 - 11.1)/(39 - 3)}, {c, 1.9/2}, {d, 4*2 Pi/48}}, x];

Show[ListPlot[myData, Frame -> True], 
 Plot[{10 + 0.04*x + 1*Sin[2*Pi/12*x], myFit[x]}, {x, 1, 48}]]
```

[image: Raw data and fit]

(Note that @lowriniak's use of `Method="NMinimize"` converges to the right answer even using the default initial values.  So that would be good to use.  But for me using *Mathematica* 10.4.1, `Method="CongugateGradient"` still requires better starting values).

My final advice would be to consult a statistician or ask on [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: `NMinimize[]` is (supposed to be) a global optimizer, so one often gets better results with it. It is much slower, however (due to its need to be thorough) and can still be trapped by local extrema for sufficiently perverse data and starting points. So, one cannot fully abandon the responsibility of choosing good seeds.

Answer (score 2):

I will not comment much on the internal differences of `NonlinearModelFit` and `TimeSeriesModelFit`, but in your specific case you can get a good fit using `Method -> "ConjugateGradient"` or `Method -> "NMinimize"`.  More detail can be found here:

- [tutorial/UnconstrainedOptimizationConjugateGradientMethods](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/UnconstrainedOptimizationConjugateGradientMethods.html)
- [tutorial/UnconstrainedOptimizationOverview](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/UnconstrainedOptimizationOverview.html)

[image: new fit]